# How to get minimal free date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have mysql table records with property time and I want to insert new record with specified time, but if there is some other record with same time I need to shift new record time for specified interval until there will be no record at same time.
So I need sql query, which find me minimal free time from specified time, which is n-time shifted for specified interval. 
For example if there is records with times 1,2,4,5,7 and new record with time 2 and interval 2, the query will return 6.

Answer (score 0):

You need a table where all possible times are stored. Then left join the `times` table with the all_times and find a record where actual_time match is null.

```
select min(at.time) as desired_free_time_value
from all_times at
     left join times t on at.time=t.time
where t.time is null
  and at.time>:desiredTimeParameter
```